# How to post multiple parameters/json value via php curl

Tags: php, curl

I need a little bit help with php curl.
I've a json which was working fine with one parameter on server (leadobj) but not working for multiple parameters like AddLead(leadobj,null) Could you help me to share the idea how can I pass values to this format. Thanks in advance.

```
$curl_data = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_data, CURLOPT_URL,"https://serviceapi");
curl_setopt($curl_data, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_data, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string);
curl_setopt($curl_data, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json;'
));
curl_setopt($curl_data, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($curl_data);
curl_close ($curl_data);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example of your JSON as well.

Comment: All JSON is handled the same way.  As long as it is _valid_ JSON, it doesn't matter how many attributes are in it.

Comment: "not working" is not a helpful problem description. *How* is it not working? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?